# How can you strengthen lower back at home?

Tags: strength-training, training, lower-back, lower-body-strength

Following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tnATDflg4o) are there any exercises I can do at home with no equipment but my body weight in order to strengthen my lower back? Is there a way to indicate my progress over time? I would like to know if there are any exercises that do not obligate contact between back to floor or any other surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

learn back levers, they are beginner friendly and can be adjusted to target the back more.

(if you can bench your own weight then you can easily back lever)

an even easier version is the nordic hinge.
here's a tutorial on how to do it

https://youtu.be/w1b5H_loiVU

after about 2 weeks the nordic hinge will become too easy, to make it harder use weighted plates or put some pillows 80 centimetres in front of you and do glute hamstring raises instead.

Answer (score 1):

No doubt strengthening lower back can make your workout to the next-level. Following workout can be helpful in strengthening your back
1-Pelvic tilts
2-Laying lateral leg tilts
3-Cat stretches
4-Supermans
5-Partial Curls
The most important aspect of exercises for lower back is you should keep your posture correct and wear the necessary equipment to support your back. If you are looking for advanced exercises for back then you can follow this workout plan https://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/advanced-back-training-1.htm
While for supporting your back during advanced training you should wear weight lifting belt because it supports the back muscles and spin. Here https://www.aqfsports.com/blogs/news/definitive-weightlifting-belts-guide  you can see the benefits of wearing it during lifting heavy weight.